# deallocation of memory allocated in std::string in C++

Tags: c++, memory

For instance I have static declaration of string

```
std::string s("test");
```

The memory will be allocated dynamically for the string. When the string `s` goes out of scope
the memory allocated for string will be deallocated ?

In case of `std::map`

```
std::map <std::string, std::string> testMap;
```

Similarly if this `testMap` also goes out of scope, the destructors of the `std::string` are called and string's memory will be deallocated ?

Comments ?
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to answers already posted, I have to notice that `std::string` and `std::map` (as well as other containers) use *allocators* for memory management. Particularly this means that after `deallocate()` they return memory back to allocator, but not to *system* directly, and it is allocator (or STL implementation) depended will it be returned to system or not. Because calling system memory management (like `malloc()`) could be heavy enough, *some* allocators do not return memory, so next call to `allocate()` will be much faster if some preallocated block exists. Sometimes it may leads to spurious memory leaks detected by various tools.

Comment: Is there any way to know if STL implementation is returning back the memory to the system ?

Comment: The only way to know for sure is to write your own allocator. That way you can control the behaviour yourself. Be careful, though. Writing a proper allocator is not easy.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Quite helpful. :)

Comment: @Chaitanya: obviously the simplest way is to dive into sources and check `std::allocator` implementation. And, BTW, it is depended on allocator blocks of which size it will returns to system or hold for further (re)allocations (yep, block size usually taken into account).

Comment: Or else is there any way to make the allocator to leave the memory back to the system ? That would be quite helpful.

Comment: @Chaitanya: as I told you before it completely depends on your STL implementation. For example, default allocator in modern gcc will do (last time I explore it (around gcc 4.3-4.4), it was a simple "wrapper" around new/delete), but most sophisticated allocators woudn't (oce again: depending on block size)... because they built to speedup allocation/deallocation when used from containers.

Answer (score 5):

If you're talking about the dynamic allocation that goes on *inside* of `std::string`, then yes, it will be deallocated automatically.

If you're using `new` to allocate the actual `std::string`, then you need to use `delete` afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

When using the standard C++ containers, all allocated memory is automatically deallocated. You don't have to worry about doing it yourself.